# Do published papers have to contain original work?

Tags: publications, research-process, thesis, mathematics, publishers

Can I turn my MSc thesis into a paper and can the paper get published if it does not have original work?

Comment: Is your thesis not original work? Or are you asking if your published thesis can later be published in a journal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "mathematics" tag leads me to think that by "original work" you mean new theorems or at least new proofs of known theorems.  It's entirely possible to publish purely expository papers that do not contain original work in that sense.  Of course, such papers still have to make an intellectual contribution that is not already in the literature. That contribution might, for example,  be an improved arrangement of the material, highlighting connections that were not evident in earlier work.  Or it might be reformulating some known results in a way that facilitated applications.

Comment: _It's entirely possible to publish purely expository papers_... only in the very small number of journals that publish such papers. Also, it's important to note that expository papers will have almost no value to an academic career in math, except in very rare cases of a paper that makes some truly brilliant expository contribution (e.g. a very insightful expository account of Ramanujan's Lost Notebook); a master's thesis will usually not meet that high standard, so aside from the fun of publishing the paper, it will not help you as much as publishing a paper with original research.